# Eclipse: New maven/spring boot project errors

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I've already checked many of the same questions asked on here for help on this, but none have helped.

Today I decided to try out spring boot. Following a tutorial that started with creating a new Maven project, I got errors in the the Pom as when implementing the  it said it couldn't find the release at the repository. This was solved by adding a repository tag, with id and url. After this I have errors in my App.java file which says - "SpringBootApplication cannot be resolved to a type". Basically everything with spring is showing this same error, that it can't be resolved to a type.

App.java

```
package com.boot.das_boot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project 
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0                  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>das-boot</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>das-boot</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
  <start-class>com.boot.das_boot.App</start-class>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

  <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting spring-boot-autoconfigure folder from your local maven repository ({YOUR_LOCAL_REPO}\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure) and downloading it again. It solved the problem for me. I think the jar was corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

The dependencies are corrupted, please try to delete the folder `org.springframework.boot` in your .m2.
After that, launch again the project with the command `mvn clean install package`.

Good luck